# How to get current logged in user id in odoo and node js

Tags: node.js, express, odoo

I want to display the current logged in user-id.  I'm using [odoo-xmlrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc) node module to connect my express and odoo application.

```
odoo.execute_kw("res.users", "search_read", params, function( err,result) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
          res.json(result);
        });
```

here I can return all users. But I want to return the current user. I have found [this](http://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2018/08/get-current-logged-in-user-id-in-odoo.html)
article which is done with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [connect](https://github.com/faisalsami/odoo-xmlrpc/blob/master/lib/index.js#L52) method returns the current logged user-id `uid` after a successful login.
You can get it there:

```
odoo.connect(function (err, uid) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
    console.log('uid', uid)  
});
```